# switching between front and back camera while recording in reeact native

Tags: react-native, camera

i want to switch camera while recording . but when  i change the camera video recodring end. how can i acheive this in react native

```
           <RNCamera
            ref={camRef}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            type={isFront ? RNCamera.Constants.Type.front : RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
            useNativeZoom={true}
            captureAudio={true}
            flashMode={flashMode === "off" ? RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off : flashMode === "on" ? RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on : RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
            autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}/>
```